# How to add content assist (auto completion) feature to my own xml editor created for eclipse?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, xsd, code-assist, xml-editor

I developed an xml editor as an eclipse plugin and now I want to provide content assist feature for it via providing a xsd. How to do it?

Comment: I read it actually. But it does not talk about giving a xsd to get content assist suggestions. It talks about just normal content assist for anything. But my questio is specfic. I have developed an XML editor plugin for eclipse and I want to get content assistance via a xsd file, but not by manually setting each of them.

Comment: Eclipse has no support for that, you will have to work out the code for that yourself.

Comment: I don't mean just a solution from eclipse itself. Is there a way to do it in the source code of the plugin. When developing the xml editor plugin can I do it by coding using some kind of java implementation? Actually when working with eclipse's original xml editor, there is a feature to provide a XSD as a "xml category" and use it to get content assist as well to validate the xml against that given xsd. I want to know how it it done in there?